# Why are Walter and Georgina servants of the Armitage family?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-out

Towards the ending of *Get Out* (2017), it is revealed that Grandpa Armitage and his wife had their conciousnesses transferred to Walter and Gerrgina respectively. If so, why are Walter and Georgina still servants of the Armitage family? There is a scene in which Rose's mom is rude towards Georgina. In the video Chris was shown during phase 2 of the Coagula procedure, Grandpa Armitage appears to be the leader of their cult, why would he transfer his consciousness into Walter's body and be the house help?

Comment: They only pretend to be the help when there's a victim coming over.